# Continous collision happening in Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity, collision-detection, javascript

I am working on Unity2d. I have a game object called `gameobject1` on screen. It holds an image (named "state"). When I drag a tree on a `gameobject1` collision is happening continuosly in the same layer instead of once. I already added Physics2Ds component `Rigidbody2D` on to tree object. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use OnCollisionEnter2d() method here so collision detection happen for one time only. If you want any collision detection then there is no requirement of rigidbody.

If I can't able to understand you question then ask it specifically.

Comment: :When i remove the rigidbody, collision is not happening ...                        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
 {                                                                  if (col.gameObject.name == "north" )
  {                                                          Debug.Log(col.gameObject.tag);                                                   }

Comment: Without any if statement check for collision. This method is called for any time or not and for which two objects?

Comment: if the condition is not specified how can we tel which object is collided with another

Comment: At present just only check you collision method called or not!! :)

Comment: ok i chkd .... not working .... but its fine when i add rigidbody....

Comment: Now update your question and give full detail what you are doing actually for you game. Because at present it is too much difficult to judge your problem. Also ask question in unity forum because in that you get help from many members. Also when I become free I will help you at present I am in work.